# Get callback from custom tab in office backstage

Tags: c#, callback, ms-office, ribbon

I created a custom tab at the backstage view in Office 2010. Like [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff936214%28v=office.14%29.aspx).

Now what i want to have is an event, that triggers when my tab is being pressed. Unfortunately the tab does not have an OnAction method or something like that.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

There is no such event for tabs. But you can specify getVisible callback for any control on that tab. Thus, the callback will be invoked at least when the tab is clicked for the first time.

You can read more about the Fluent UI (aka Ribbon UI) in the following series of articles in MSDN:

- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 1 of 3)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338202(v=office.12).aspx)
- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 2 of 3)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338199(v=office.12).aspx)
- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 3 of 3)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa722523(v=office.12).aspx)